# Помогите сгенерировать исключение в qt qreator

Tags: исключения, qtcreator, c++

вот код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test{
private:
    int * var;
public:
    test();
    ~test();
};

test::test(){
    var = new int;
}

test::~test(){

}

int main(){
    try{
        test * tp;
        tp = new test;

        delete tp;

        int a = 10 / 0;
    }

    catch (...){
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

должен сгенерировать исключение но увы. раньше писал на msvs ловилось без проблем и даже срабатывало без своего "отлова" (выбрасывало окно с сообщением), а тут в qtcreator молча отрабатывает и все. обычный non-qt c++ проект и не ловится ни в debug ни в release версиях.

Comment: А без класса `test` воспроизводится?

    int main(){
        try{
            int a = 10 / 0;
        }
        catch (...){
            cout << "error" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }

Comment: тот же результат

Comment: отлично. (тогда, может быть, уберите ненужный код из примера?)

а вот так:

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        cout << "before" << endl;
        try { cout << "try" << endl; int a = 10 / 0; }
        catch (...) { cout << "catch" << endl; }
        cout << "after" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

Comment: before]

    try

    Press <RETURN> to close this window...


Заметил странность. если запускать из под пользователя и не из IDE то реагирует на int a = 10 / 0; (пишет: исключение плавающей точки, сделан дамп), под рутом ничего не пишит

Comment: А, туман начинает проясняться. Выходит, что (1) `catch(...)` не отрабатывает, (2) IDE не сообщает об аварийном завершении.

Вот ещё странность: http://ideone.com/fSHV9g (нету "catch" — почему?)

Под рутом может быть запрещён дамп в настройках.

Comment: по видимому GDB ничего не знает о стандартных исключениях. вот так он ловит:

    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdexcept>
    
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
    try { throw ""; }
    catch ( ... ){ cout << "error" << endl; }
    return 0;
    }

Comment: О, нашёл: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4748042/276994

Короче, деление на 0 может и не бросить exception. Проверяйте перед делением :-)